# Indexing repeated elements in a vector

Tags: r, indexing

I would like to take a vector:

```
x <- c(rep("cat",3), rep("dog",2))

[1] "cat" "cat" "cat" "dog" "dog"
```

and turn it into:

```
[1] "cat_a" "cat_b" "cat_c" "dog_a" "dog_b"
```

Where each unique element is index with "_" plus a letter.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237443/assign-unique-value-for-duplicated-rows

Answer (score 4):

Using base functions you can do

```
ave(x, x, FUN=function(x) paste(x, letters[seq_along(x)], sep="_"))
# [1] "cat_a" "cat_b" "cat_c" "dog_a" "dog_b"
```